# Проблема парсинга html на heroku node.js

Tags: node.js, парсер, heroku

```
const parseAucInfo = async (url: string): Promise<IAucInfo> => {
  const data = await fetch(url).then((response: any) => response.text());
  console.log(data); }
```

запускаю этот код на своем пк и мне приходит разметка с нужной информацией, если запускаю его на сервере heroku то приходит разметка с сообщением с ошибкой

```
 <div class="attribution">
DDoS protection by <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing/" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a>
<br />
<span class="ray_id">Ray ID: <code>618381797960a729</code></span>
</div>
```

можно как-то обойти эту  проблему? Или только смена хостинга для скрипта?

Comment: Предполагаю, что эту защиту можно обойти каким-нибудь прокси. Пробовали?

Comment: я потыкал сайт через впн в браузере, защита выскакивает каждый раз когда запрашиваю страницу с нового IP и после 5-10 секунд перенаправляет на нужную страницу, дальше уже без нее
я так понял в теории мне надо на heroku запустить headless браузер и продержать соединение 10+сек один раз